# Python Classes - Using Instances AS Attributes

Tags: python, class, oop, attributes, instance

I'm currently learning/working with classes in Python 3.10.2 as of writing this. What I am trying to achieve is to create a class instance which is an attribute within another class.

Here is some code I've been working on to help demonstrate my point.

```py
class Vehicle():
    """To model a basic vehicle"""
    def __init__(self, name, max_speed, millage):
        """Initiate class variables"""
        self.name = name
        self.max_speed = max_speed
        self.millage = millage
        self.tyre = Tyre()

    def vehicle_details(self):
        """display vehicle details"""
        return f"\nName: {self.name.title()}, Max speed: {self.max_speed}MPH, Millage: {self.millage} "

class Tyre():
    """A class specific for vehicle tyres"""
    def __init__(self, size=16, pressure=36):
        self.size = size
        self.pressure = pressure

    def tyre_details(self):
        """Print tyre details."""
        print(f'Tyre size: {self.size} inches.')
        print(f"Tyre pressure {self.pressure} PSI.")
```

In the `Vehicle` class, I add `Tyre()` as an attribute.

Now this code DOES work and I can call the `Tyre` methods through my `Vehicle` instances, but only when I allocate pre-determined values to `size` and `pressure` within the `Tyre` class.

Is there either:

1. A way I can achieve this without having to allocate the pre-determined values within the `Tyre` class?

   This is the Traceback I receive if I do not allocate the pre-determined values:

   ```
   TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'size' and 'pressure'
   ```
2. An easy way for me to overwrite the pre-determined values when calling this class and its methods if I am unable to remove the pre-determined values?

Comment: You should probably google object creation and constructors in Python, that would be the first thing to look for. Essentially, your vehicle would also then need to take a specific tyre size and pressure value for it to have tyres with proper values, if that makes any sense. So you should add the `size` and `pressure` parameters to the vehicle class constructor as: `def __init__(self, name, max_speed, millage, tyre_size, tyre_pressure)` and pass them into the Tyre when creating it as: `self.tyre = Tyre(tyre_size,tyre_pressure)`

Comment: I'm not sure what this has to do with the `Vehicle` class. Wouldn't you have the same questions when you only had the `Tyre` class on its own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are almost infinite ways to "solve" this, but I'll present a few.

None are "right", all involve tradeoffs and over time you'll learn which make sense where.

#### Passthrough arguments

```
class Vehicle():
    """To model a basic vehicle"""
    def __init__(self, name, max_speed, millage, tyre_size, tyre_pressure):
        """Initiate class variables"""
        self.name = name
        self.max_speed = max_speed
        self.millage = millage
        self.tyre = Tyre(tyre_size, tyre_pressure)

    def vehicle_details(self):
        """display vehicle details"""
        return f"\nName: {self.name.title()}, Max speed: {self.max_speed}MPH, Millage: {self.millage} "


class Tyre():
    """A class specific for vehicle tyres"""
    def __init__(self, size, pressure):
        self.size = size
        self.pressure = pressure

    def tyre_details(self):
        """Print tyre details."""
        print(f'Tyre size: {self.size} inches.')
        print(f"Tyre pressure {self.pressure} PSI.")

v1 = Vehicle("VehicleName", 120, 50_000, 16, 36)
# Or, with named arguments
v2 = Vehicle(
    name = "VehicleName", 
    max_speed = 120, 
    millage = 50_000, 
    tyre_size = 16, 
    typre_pressure = 36
)
```

Here, you're just passing the `Tyre` constructor's arguments through from the `Vehicle` constructor to your construction of `Tyre`.  If every time you construct a `Vehicle` you'll know the `Tyre` specifications, this is fine.  If not, you'll likely want an alternative.

#### Construct `Vehicle` with `Tyre` instance as argument

```
class Vehicle():
    """To model a basic vehicle"""
    def __init__(self, name, max_speed, millage, tyre):
        """Initiate class variables"""
        self.name = name
        self.max_speed = max_speed
        self.millage = millage
        self.tyre = tyre

    def vehicle_details(self):
        """display vehicle details"""
        return f"\nName: {self.name.title()}, Max speed: {self.max_speed}MPH, Millage: {self.millage} "


class Tyre():
    """A class specific for vehicle tyres"""
    def __init__(self, size, pressure):
        self.size = size
        self.pressure = pressure

    def tyre_details(self):
        """Print tyre details."""
        print(f'Tyre size: {self.size} inches.')
        print(f"Tyre pressure {self.pressure} PSI.")


v = Vehicle(
    name = "VehicleName", 
    max_speed = 120, 
    millage = 50_000, 
    tyre = Tyre(16, 36)
)
```

Similar to the previous option, but in the previous option each `Vehicle` had their own `Tyre` instance.  Here you can "share" `Tyre` objects.  Probably not a huge deal in this case, but something to keep in mind, especially when you work with larger or more complex objects and/or where sharing becomes a benefit.

Sharing `Tyre` instances might look like:

```
standard_tyre = Tyre(16, 36)

v1 = Vehicle(
    name = "VehicleOne", 
    max_speed = 120, 
    millage = 50_000, 
    tyre = standard_tyre,
)
v2 = Vehicle(
    name = "VehicleTwo", 
    max_speed = 140, 
    millage = 20_000, 
    tyre = standard_tyre,
)
```

#### Setting tyre later, outside of the constructor

```
class Vehicle():
    """To model a basic vehicle"""
    def __init__(self, name, max_speed, millage):
        """Initiate class variables"""
        self.name = name
        self.max_speed = max_speed
        self.millage = millage
        self.tyre = None

    def vehicle_details(self):
        """display vehicle details"""
        return f"\nName: {self.name.title()}, Max speed: {self.max_speed}MPH, Millage: {self.millage} "


class Tyre():
    """A class specific for vehicle tyres"""
    def __init__(self, size, pressure):
        self.size = size
        self.pressure = pressure

    def tyre_details(self):
        """Print tyre details."""
        print(f'Tyre size: {self.size} inches.')
        print(f"Tyre pressure {self.pressure} PSI.")


v = Vehicle(
    name = "VehicleName", 
    max_speed = 120, 
    millage = 50_000, 
)
v.tyre = Tyre(16,36)
```

Maybe you don't know what the specifics of the `Tyre` are when you're creating the `Vehicle`, but you still want a `Vehicle` instance.

Answer (score 6):

> 1. A way I can achieve this without having to allocate the pre-determined values within the Tyre class?

A possible solution might be to pass the arguments for `Tyre` when initializing the `Vehicle`:

```py
class Vehicle:

    def __init__(self, name, max_speed, millage, tyre_size=16, tyre_pressure=36):
        """Initiate class variables"""
        self.name = name
        self.max_speed = max_speed
        self.millage = millage
        self.tyre = Tyre(size=tyre_size, pressure=tyre_pressure)
```

> 2. An easy way for me to overwrite the pre-determined values when calling this class and its methods if I am unable to remove the pre-determined values?

You can simply not use any pre-determined values, requiring them to being explicitly provided:

```py
class Tyre:

    def __init__(self, size, pressure):
        # ...
```

If no value is passed an exception will be raised. You should rely on the pre-determined values only if you really want to. Instead of always relying on a specific set of pre-determined values.

In general,I would suggest only using pre-determined values when you rarely need a different value from the default. For example, if you have a `User` class probably you'll always use a different `username`. There's no obvious default value. In the other hand, when you have a `Vehicle` class, in most of the cases it will have 4 doors, but sometimes might be different (maybe 5), so you can 4 as default and change it when you need.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the arguments when creating the instance of the `Tyre` class. The pre-determined values are only used when no argument is passed in, so if you do `self.tyre = Tyre(size goes here, pressure goes here)`, it won't use the pre-determined values.

Answer (score -1):

1. I ran the following after your code and it worked fine for me.

```
veh = Vehicle('Volkswagen', 200, 10)
print(veh.tyre.tyre_details())
```

Output:

```
Tyre size: 16 inches.
Tyre pressure 36 PSI.
```

2. Overwriting tyre size and pressure through vehicle instance:

```
veh.tyre.size = 17
veh.tyre.pressure = 38
print(veh.tyre.tyre_details())
```

Output

```
Tyre size: 17 inches.
Tyre pressure 38 PSI.
```

Maybe you are accessing the tyre instance incorrectly.

Comment: Yes, this is what I am getting too. However, If I remove the pre-determined values it does not work even if I include:

veh.tyre.size = 17 etc etc

Comment: If you remove the predetermined values then you are not giving the Tyre class the arguments it needs.
Then some of the above answers will do fine.